# Count occurence of a list in different arrays (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have a list like this :

```
var list = [apple, watermelon, pineapple]
```

And an array like this :

```
var array = { 
fruit : [ [apple], [apple, watermelon], [pineapple, watermelon], [watermelon], [pineapple], [apple, pineapple] ]

count : [4, 7, 5, 3, 3, 2]
}
```

I want to create a new array with the occurence of each fruits and to obtain this :

```
result = 
{
fruits : [apple, watermelon, pineapple]
count : [13, 15, 10]
```

I tried this :

```
var result = {
    trigger : [apple, watermelon, pineapple],
    count : []
}
for (i=0; i < array.fruits.length; i++){
    var k = 0
    for (j in result.trigger){
        if (array.fruits[i].includes(j)) {
            k += array.count[i]
        }
        result.count.push(k)
    }
}
```

But I get 0 for all counts

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Please present a proper [mre] of the issue to begin with, and not pseudo-code which we would have to fix in several places first, to get a workable example.

Comment: Basic debugging is not rocket science. Add a `console.log(array.fruits[i], j)` before that `if` statement, and then go check the browser console and look at _what_ you are actually checking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first reason you're getting all zeros is because you're iterating on `array.fruits`, but you've defined `array` with the property `fruit` (no s), so this shouldn't even run (since `array.fruits` is `undefined`, when it then tries to call `undefined.length` you will get a runtime error)

Next, you are looking at `j in result.trigger`, but you want to be looking at `j of result.trigger`.  Note: the `in` keyword looks at the keys of the array `result.trigger`, which in this case is just the indices of the array.  The `of` keyword looks at the values of the array, which seems to be what you want here

Once you fix those issues, your code will run but you'll get the wrong output of `count: [4, 4, 4, 7, 14, 14, 0, 5, 10, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 4]`.  This is because your outer for loop is iterating on `array.fruit`, and your inner for loop on `result.trigger`.  Insider your inner-most for loop you have a `push()` call. Since `array.fruit` has 6 entries and `result.trigger` has 3 entries, you end up with 18 entries in `count`, which is not what you said you wanted.

Since you want `result.count` to end with 3 entries, you need to make sure the number of times you call `push()` matches the length of trigger.  In other words, your outer-most loop must be iterating on `result.trigger`.  If you swap the positions of your inner and outer loops, and move the `push()` to the outer loop you get the result you expect.

```js
const result = {
  trigger: ['apple', 'watermelon', 'pineapple'],
  count: [],
};
for (let j of result.trigger) {
  let k = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.fruit.length; i++) {
    if (array.fruit[i].includes(j)) {
      k += array.count[i];
    }
  }
  result.count.push(k);
}
```

Note: there were some errors in your original code, like iterating on `array.fruits` instead of `array.fruit`.  Also in your for loops you do not add `var` or `let` before `i` and `j`, which produces a runtime error since neither of those variables are defined anywhere.  I would recommend using some sort of debugger to step through your code, personally I use a web browser and it helps a ton to add breakpoints and step through each line.

As others have shown, there's a lot of syntax sugar to make the code more concise (albeit harder to pick up if you're new to JS).  One recommendation I have is that right now your different data source and result containers are very loosely connected.  The only real connection between `result.trigger` and `result.count` is you assume that the entries at the same index correspond to one another.  But to another developer reading your code, they may not pick up on this right away.

My suggestion is to keep associated data together in objects.  For example,

```js
const result = {
  trigger: ['apple', 'watermelon', 'pineapple'],
  count: [],
};
```

would turn in to

```js
const result = {
  apple: 0,
  watermelon: 0,
  pineapple: 0,
};
```

This way the count of each fruit is directly associated with the fruit itself.  Putting that together with some syntax sugar you can make the code a lot more self-descriptive yet concise.

The last thing I would suggest is to make use of JS Objects as maps.  Iterating over arrays repeatedly with calls like `includes()` can become slower with larger arrays, but since we know the fruit names we are looking for, we can use those to speed up our search by using the entries of `array.fruit` as keys to our `result` object.

We can also build in some runtime protection from fruits that were not included in the original list with this line

```js
if (result[fruit] != undefined) result[fruit] += array.count[idx];
```

Putting everything together we get this:

```js
const list = ["apple", "watermelon", "pineapple"];
const result = Object.fromEntries(list.map(fruit => [fruit, 0])); // syntatic sugar way to initialize the results without needing to re-type the fruit names
const array = {
  fruit: [
    ["apple"],
    ["apple", "watermelon"],
    ["pineapple", "watermelon"],
    ["watermelon"],
    ["pineapple"],
    ["apple", "pineapple"],
  ],
  count: [4, 7, 5, 3, 3, 2],
};

for (const [idx, subArr] of Object.entries(array.fruit)) {
  for (const fruit of subArr) {
    if (result[fruit] != undefined) result[fruit] += array.count[idx];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list = ['apple', 'watermelon', 'pineapple']

var array = {
  fruit: [
    ['apple'],
    ['apple', 'watermelon'],
    ['pineapple', 'watermelon'],
    ['watermelon'],
    ['pineapple'],
    ['apple', 'pineapple']
  ],

  count: [4, 7, 5, 3, 3, 2]
}

const values = Array(list.length).fill(0)

// for each item of array.fruit
for (let i = 0; i < array.fruit.length; i += 1) {
  // for each fruit in subarray
  for (const fr of array.fruit[i]) {
    // find index in list
    const index = list.indexOf(fr)
    // add count of fruits
    values[index] += array.count[i]
  }
}

 

console.log(values)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation, not just a piece of code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and check in [each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iteration whether a fruit in `array.fuits[i]` is in your `list`. If that is the case increase the according counter in your reducer accumulator.

```js
const list = ["apple", "watermelon", "pineapple"];
const array = {
  fruit: [
    ["apple"],
    ["apple", "watermelon"],
    ["pineapple", "watermelon"],
    ["watermelon"],
    ["pineapple"],
    ["apple", "pineapple"]
  ],
  count: [4, 7, 5, 3, 3, 2]
};

const result = array.fruit.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  curr.forEach(fruit => (acc[list.indexOf(fruit)] += array.count[i]));
  return acc;
}, Array(list.length).fill(0));

console.log(result);
```